# Getting the redefinition error for virtual destructor

Tags: c++

I've the following C++ snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A()
    {
    }
};

A::~A()
{
    
}

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting these errors?:

> error: redefinition of 'A::~A()' A::~A()
>
> error: 'virtual A::~A()' previously defined here
>
> ```
>  virtual ~A()**
> ```

Comment: The error is self explanatory - you have 2 implementations of the destructor

Comment: Change  virtual ~A(){} to virtual ~A();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the following in your class

```
virtual ~A();
```

instead of

```
virtual ~A()
             {
              }
```

The compiler is actually telling you exactly what the problem is here. You have two implementations - one inline in your class and another  outside it here

```
A::~A()
{

}
```

you cannot have both.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between **declaration** and **definition**. C++ follows the [ODR - One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), that is: **you need to define stuff only ONCE**.

- Declaration = you let the world know something exists and how the parameters/return types are
- Definition = you write the actual code for that function/class/object/whatever

In your code you have TWO definitions and one declaration. That violates the ODR:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() < - declares a virtual destructor
    { <- defines the code (nothing) for the virtual destructor
    }
};

A::~A() <- defines the code AGAIN for the virtual destructor of the class A
{

}

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is not allowed and thus the error. If the defines were:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A()
    { 
       printf("World?");
    }
};

A::~A()
{
   printf("Hello?");
}
```

The compiler wouldn't know if you wanted to print "Hello?" or "World?".

The *virtual* keyword doesn't help here since it only says: "if a class derives from this one and has a destructor, use polymorphism". It's out-of-topic talking about polymorphism here so I'll let it go.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the destructor twice - once inline in the class, once outside. You need e.g. to change the inline definition to declaration only:

```
virtual ~A();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a definition of the destructor inside the class definition

```
class A
{
    public:

               virtual ~A()
                     {
                      }
    };
```

and this is also the destructor definition outside the class definition.

```
 A::~A()
{

}
```

So you defined the destructor twice and the compiler reports about this mistake.

You could define the destructor inside the class the following way

```
class A
{
    public:

               virtual ~A() = default;
};
```